# C Struct read/ write garbage value to file

Tags: c, file-io, struct, garbage

I am diving into C after long time and struggling with reading and writing struct to the simple text file. I debuged this prog and I found out its reading and writing garbage value to the file. Can someone help me. Here is my code

```
#define MAX_UserName_LEN 16
#define MAX_Password_LEN 8
#define MAX_FileName_LEN 32

struct userDetails
{
char userName[MAX_UserName_LEN];
char password[MAX_Password_LEN];
};

int registration(struct userDetails userInfo)
{
FILE *userDb;
userDb= fopen("UserDataBase.txt","a");
if(fwrite(&userInfo,sizeof(userInfo),1,userDb))
{
    fclose(userDb);
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}

}

int authenicate(struct userDetails userInfo)
{
FILE *userDb;
struct userDetails temp;
userDb = fopen("UserDataBase.txt","r");
while(!feof(userDb))
{
  fread(&temp,sizeof(temp),1,userDb);
  if (temp.userName==userInfo.userName && temp.password==userInfo.password)
  {
    printf("Logged In Sucessfully");
    return 1;
  }
 }
 return 0;

}
```

In main function, I an just declaring one struct variable and accepting user input into that struct and passing it to both above mentioned functions.

Comment: Why do you think that its reading and writing **garbage**? You're writing binary data. Don't expect it miraculously to become text.

Comment: Actually, this case, it will definitely write garbage to the file. (the garbage being the stuff after the terminating-nulls) But when the data is read back, it will still be correct inside the program. EDIT: I take that back, this would be the case if format was "rb" and "wb+".

Comment: can you give me some pointers to the difference between normal read write operations and binary read write operations ?

Answer (score 3):

The first major problem I see is here:

```
if (temp.userName==userInfo.userName && temp.password==userInfo.password)
```

You are trying to compare strings with `==`. You need to use `strcmp()` instead:

```
if (strcmp(temp.userName, userInfo.userName) == 0 && 
    strcmp(temp.password, userInfo.password) == 0)
```

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the "garbage" you're getting, but it's definitely an error.

As your code stands right now, it will never enter the if-statement.

Comment: Speaking of errors, fopen()'s return value must be checked for NULL and authenicate() must close the file prior to returning.

Comment: Not only that, there also needs to be another `fclose` in `else` part of the `registration()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Write a short code, which prints the userlist, so you'll see wheter the file contains garbage or not.

Anyway, passwords should be scrambled somehow. Even a dumb solution is better than nothing, just to make it non-readable for human eyes. Say, *for (n = 0; n < strlen(pwd); n++) pwd[n] ^= 0x55;*.